Formatting all tildes in a Word Document with VBA
I'm trying to create a script that finds all tildes in my document and formats them with a predefined formatting. I've gotten very close, my current code formats all except the first tilde in the document. I'm not sure how I would fix this. This is my current code:
Sub FormatTilde()

    Set TildeStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Approx")
    'Start from the beginning of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute FindText:="~"
        Do While .Execute = True
            Selection.Style = TildeStyle
        Loop
    End With
    

End Sub

Basically the "Approx" style is what I'm formatting it with, it changes the font to one that has the tilde in the middle of the characters instead of the top, which the document font does.
I'm not sure why the first instance is not formatted and what to do to fix it, so any help would be appreciated.

Your code docesn't work because it executes a second execute before the first tilde is reformatted. In any event, you don't need the loop. Try:
Sub FormatTilde()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Text = "~"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Style = "Approx"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


This is somewhat similar than my first attempts. What your code does (although the .Replacement.Style = "Approx" just breaks) is that it formats the whole paragraph. I want to keep the font for the paragraph, but only format the tilde, nothing else.

Which is precisely what the code I posted does. Did you at least try it? NOTE: If your "Approx" Style is a Paragraph Style, then formatting the whole paragraph is to be expected. You need to use a Character Style if you only want to format specific characters.

While macropod's answer didn't work, it did get me to the right track and I managed to make the code work. It might not be the most elegant solution, but it does what I need it to do:
Sub FormatTilde()

    Set TildeStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Approx")
    'Start from the beginning of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute FindText:="~"
        Selection.Style = TildeStyle
        Do While Selection.Find.Execute
            Selection.Style = TildeStyle
        Loop
    End With
    
    ActiveDocument.UndoClear

End Sub



And, if your code finds nothing, guess what's going to happen...
